# CSS Reset Question

Tags: css, reset

The Eric A. Meyer CSS reset defines all elements names, for example:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

My Question is, is it okay to use star selector instead of defining all elements like above?

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

If yes, which is better to use? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since the listet names are **not** "all elements names", you shouldn't use `*` - note that theres no `input`, `select` or `textarea` listet, just to give a few examples.

Answer (score 3):

You want to shy away from `*` because of perfomance reasons, see

- [Performance Impact of CSS Selectors](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/)
- [Simplifying CSS Selectors](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you allready accepted an answer, but i wanted to let you know that it mignt NOT be OK to set everything (*) with margin:0; padding:0;font-size:100;etc:etc;

**Unless you are ready to write over your reset a long AND complete set of html markups and possibilities.**

Consider a `<select><option>` and other `<form>` fields : they will become crunched an tiny.

Consider a `<ul><li>`  and  `<ol><li>`  and nested `<ol><li><ol><li>`  : they will become all straight, vertically aligned and justified to 0.

Consider a `<small>`, `<sup>`, `<sub>` and other inline markups. They will all look the same (opposite of what css is meant for)

My answer is : **NO, it is not OK to do: `* {margin:0;padding:0; /* ... */}`** unless you don't care about the browser DOM speed or having to deal, afterward, with the consequences on your visual styling ( woups! form fields are all messed up, woups! my cite is not showing, woups! paragraph looks like anything else, woups! i didn't see that one comming, etc ).